# Set the shipping cost

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, joomla, virtuemart

How to set the cost of delivery by Ajax request?
I tried using this method, but it still didn't change the cost..

```
$values['shipment_cost'] = 50;
$values['shipment_package_fee'] = 90;
vmPSPlugin::storePSPluginInternalData($values);
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @user you might try asking on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.